# .includes() Checking for keywords in prompt()

Tags: javascript, arrays, prompt

I'm creating a sort of chatbot which will run on imbedded keywords stored in arrays, in this example I have array `x` being checked in `y`. This returns `true` whenever I exactly type `Hello` in the `prompt()`. However if I were to say something along the lines of **"Oh Hello There."** in the prompt, it returns false. How can I check for keywords in an array within a `prompt()` (in-between sentences)

```
var x = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Sup'];
var y = prompt("Looking for a Hello...");

if (x.includes(y)){
    alert("You Said Hello!");
} else {
    alert("No Hello Found!");
}
```

Comment: `if( x.some(word=>y.includes(x)))`

Comment: The above won’t work as it is checking for the inclusion of the entire array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to either check for each word, or use a Regular Expression like in this snippet

```js
var x = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Sup'];
var y = prompt("Looking for a Hello...");

var containsX = x.some(word=>y.includes(word))

if (containsX){
    alert("You Said Hello!");
} else {
    alert("No Hello Found!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `indexof`.

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the
>   search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

```js
let x = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Sup'];
let y = "Looking for a Hello...";

console.log(x.some(s=> y.indexOf(s)));
```