# How to switch() variable with `x.some(word=>y.includes(word))` cases

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a bot that takes a variable `command`, which is the **message a user sends**. I want to `switch(command)` and have each case return `true` whenever the content of the `command` is **found within** `myArr`. I have tried the following and has not worked. My question is what is a **better way to switch** `command`.

```
const myArr = ['hello']
//const command will be the message sent by the user

switch(command){

   case myArr.some(word=>command.includes(word)):

      console.log('You said hello')

   break;

}
```

Comment: Why you are using a switch statement? What is your main requirement here?

Comment: I plan for this to be a sort of assistant. So there will be dozens of arrays checking the users message to know which command to execute. The 'Hello' is just one example

Comment: ok, but why don't you use simple `switch(command) case 'hello'`.. what is the purpose of using `myArr` here?

Comment: The way the bot will recognize a command will be through keywords found through the users message. For example for a command that will give the time I want there to be many ways to ask for the time rather than a fixed 'Give time' command. As long as the keyword 'time' is found within the message the command will be executed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128785/includes-checking-for-keywords-in-prompt

Comment: ok, so you will have multiple arrays to hold all possible values for each command. So, like one array for hello, another array for time..

Comment: Correct, So I want to switch every possible command in each case to then execute said command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213360/discussion-between-elitezen-and-pala).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if.. else if` logic here for the current scenario like:

```js
const myArr = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Sup']
const timeArr = ['time', 'get time', 'clock']

// Get action based on command passed by user
function GetAction(command) {
  if (myArr.some(word => command.includes(word))) {
    console.log('You said hello')

  } else if (timeArr.some(word => command.includes(word))) {
    console.log('You said time')
  }
}

// Check Hello
GetAction('Hello')

setTimeout(function() {
  // Check get time after 2 seconds
  GetAction('get time')

  setTimeout(function() {
    // Check Hi after 2 seconds
    GetAction('Hi')
  }, 2000);

}, 2000);
```

Also, if you want to make it case-insensitive so that even if the user types `HELLO`, `hello`, `heLLo`, etc but we should still execute the commands then you can use [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method like:

```js
const myArr = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Sup']
const timeArr = ['time', 'get time', 'clock']

// Get action based on command passed by user
function GetAction(command) {
  if (myArr.some(word => command.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase()))) {
    console.log('You said hello')

  } else if (timeArr.some(word => command.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase()))) {
    console.log('You said time')
  }
}

// Check Hello
GetAction('HELLO')

setTimeout(function() {
  GetAction('hello')

  setTimeout(function() {
    GetAction('heLLo')
  }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```